# Stacked bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Alright, I am going crazy. So I have some data that has a bunch of columns.  Mainly names, address, and other qualities.

```
Name       ||||   Division | | |MonthNo
John ||||  Seattle | | | | | 2
Chris|||| Seattle ||||||||| 4
Dave ||||Dallas  |||||||||| 2
Suzy |||| San Fran |||| 5
Jill | | | | Dallas |||||||||| 4
```

To get a simple count of occurrence by Month I did this:

```
MC$MonthNo <- factor(MC$MonthNo, levels = c(1:11), labels = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November"))



MCH <- ggplot(na.omit(MC), aes(MonthNo))

MCH + geom_bar(color = "black", fill = "light blue") + labs(x = "2017", y = "# of Leads") + theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 3, linetype = "solid"), axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 14), axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 14)) + scale_y_continuous(name = "# Of Leads", breaks = c(0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000), limits = c(0, 3000)) + theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white"), panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "black", size = .5), panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "black", size = .5))
```

Pretty much just a basic bar graph.

Now there is a field in this data called Division.  There are 7 different divisions for example Seattle, Pittsburgh, Honolulu, Dallas, San Francisco, Salt Lake City, New Orleans.  I want to break my bars into stacks based off of which division they are in.  Like 7 different bars into 1 with the 7 segments representing the counts of each division for each month.. Like in my example Month 2 has Seattle and Dallas.  I would want there to be two segments in one bar. I can't figure this out for the life of me. Everything was imported from a CSV with a couple thousand unique rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May you rewrite you post title as a question?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.
I saved your data as csv

```
petey <-read.csv("Petey_data.txt")
#Adding a month variable, always good practice to
#keep original data as is and add variables
#I used the built-in month.abb constant to get 
#abbreviated month names
#assigned as factor with labels as month order
petey$Month <-factor(month.abb[petey$MonthNo], levels = month.abb)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(petey,aes(Month))+geom_bar(aes(fill=Division))
```

For the future please look up `?dput` to share your data
also read up on `?geom_bar` and look at the examples to get an idea of how the data is arranged. More examples on the webpage at http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much.  I plan on reading Wickham's book eventually.  I mainly work with GIS and wanted to branch out a little bit. I do have another question though.  What would I do if I wanted to only use a select few divisions, like 3 of the 7?

Comment: You can use `df = subset(petey, Division %in% c(division1, division 2, division3))` to filter your data to just the divisions you want (look up `?subset`). Then you can feed the filtered data into ggplot, like so: `ggplot(df, aes(Month)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=Division))`